# Source code of CvCaptureFromFile(..)

Tags: c++, c, opencv, video-capture

I want to use the source code of the `CvCaptureFromFile(..)` function as I do not want to use OpenCV library functions in my project. So I went inside the function by pressing F10,F11 and I copied the things I needed and converted them into C code. Till now everything was ok.

But when I tried to run I am getting linking error inside the function `icvIntFFMPEG(void)`

the errors are as follows:

> Error 1   `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) void * __stdcall GetProcAddress(struct
>   HINSTANCE__ *,char const *)"
>   (__imp_?GetProcAddress@@YGPAXPAUHINSTANCE__@@PBD@Z) referenced in
>   function "void __cdecl icvInitFFMPEG(void)" (?icvInitFFMPEG@@YAXXZ)`
>   Error 2   `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct HINSTANCE__
>   * __stdcall LoadLibrary(char const *)" (?LoadLibrary@@YGPAUHINSTANCE__@@PBD@Z) referenced in function "void
>   __cdecl icvInitFFMPEG(void)" (?icvInitFFMPEG@@YAXXZ)`

I copied everything as it is in the source code. Any idea where I am going wrong? How do I solve this error?

**UPDATE**: IF I wrap the header file (where I was coping the source code) inside an extern "C" something like this-

```
extern "C" {
  #include "defination.h"
 }
```

Then the first error is gone, and the error with loadLibrary changes to

> `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__LoadLibrary@4 referenced in function _icvInitFFMPEG`

Comment: You copied the things *you* needed, but not the things that the stuff you copied needed... Why don't you just use OpenCV directly instead of playing these "games"?

Comment: I can not use opencv thats why I am using the source code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCv uses ffmpeg - which is a really big project. And ffmpeg uses some other tools behind curtains. You may want to go using ffmpeg, but to take the source code from ffmpeg itself is foolish - you will spend years fiddling with that code - really.

So, decide on a video input library - be it OpenCV, ffmpeg, Direct3D or whatever, and use it.

Do not cling yourself on the idea that 'you cannot use external libraries' because you can't go without them. It takes years to develop such a library - I am pretty sure you do not want to go that way.

Comment: Thanks for your help, But I as have told from my instructor I cannot use external libraries :( :( in that case any idea how should I work forward..

Comment: Then you may also want to write a new operating system, a compiler and design a computer. You may have understood wrongly the requirements. If you work for an image processing course, it's natural that you write the algorithms for yourself. But the video reading is something else. You need to use a library the same way you need a monitor, a computer and a compiler. And IF your homework is to write a video decoder, do not cheat.

Comment: I am not cheating I am allowed to see the source code from opencv or any other library..I cannot directly use them..anyways thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems your get unresolved calls to LoadLibrary()/GetProcAddress() functions that are inside Kernel32.dll. What IDE/project type are you using? Kernel32.lib should be linked in by default unless /NODEFAULTLIB is specified somewhere, at least as far as I remember. You can try to add `#pragma comment(lib, "kernel32.lib")` to the file where you copied the code, but without more info about your setup it is hard to answer what is causing this.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply. I am using VS 2010 and I have linked the Kernel32.lib in the additional dependencies and aslo add #pragma comment(lib, "kernel32.lib") but still getting the same errors.